# In swipe.js what is happening in this block of code in the translate function?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand how swipe.js works so that I can build my own image slider. can you help me understand what is happening here

```
function translate(index, dist, speed) {

  var slide = slides[index];
  var style = slide && slide.style;

  if (!style) return;

  style.webkitTransitionDuration =
  style.MozTransitionDuration =
  style.msTransitionDuration =
  style.OTransitionDuration =
  style.transitionDuration = speed + 'ms';

  style.webkitTransform = 'translate(' + dist + 'px,0)' + 'translateZ(0)';
  style.msTransform =
  style.MozTransform =
  style.OTransform = 'translateX(' + dist + 'px)';

}
```

Link to [swipe.js](https://raw.github.com/bradbirdsall/Swipe/master/swipe.js)

Comment: The weird looking `=` statements?  It's all just one long line.  All the durations = speed + 'ms', and all the transforms = 'translateX(' + dist + 'px)'

Comment: Ye, Basicly the compiler starts at the left position and keeps assigning the variables to each other.

Comment: Instead of using css transform wouldn't you be better off if you started using the old jquery animate?

Comment: @aldux what makes you say that?

Comment: @JGallardo I mean that both approaches will work to some extent, but jQuery gives you cross-browser compatibility out of the box, and since it seems you're starting to learn javascript (I'm assuming that), that would be one thing less to worry about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function translate(index, dist, speed) {
  // Get the slide by index
  var slide = slides[index];

  // Get the style that is assigned to the slide.  If no slide was found
  // this will return false.
  var style = slide && slide.style;

  // If there was no style found, return (do nothing)
  if (!style) return;

  // In Javascript, you can assign multiple variables at once.  For example,
  // "var a = b = c = 10;".  That would assign all 3 variables to 10.  In the
  // code below, it assigns a transition for each custom browser (since each
  // browser has a custom attribute that it uses).  msTransitionDuration is
  // for Microsoft (IE), webkit for Chrome, Moz for Firefox, etc.  It assigns
  // each of them to be "<speed>ms", speed being a variable passed into the
  // function.  It looks strange because each variable is on it's own line,
  // but you can imagine it like the example I provided above.
  style.webkitTransitionDuration =
  style.MozTransitionDuration =
  style.msTransitionDuration =
  style.OTransitionDuration =
  style.transitionDuration = speed + 'ms';

  // Now, assign the transform methods.  Chrome uses a different format, so
  // it gets it's own string.  ms, Moz, and O are the same, so they are
  // assigned in a similar style to the block above.
  style.webkitTransform = 'translate(' + dist + 'px,0)' + 'translateZ(0)';
  style.msTransform =
  style.MozTransform =
  style.OTransform = 'translateX(' + dist + 'px)';
}
```

Comment: Oh OK I was wondering why `style.` was being repeated so much

Answer (score 1):

Here's each line, annotated:

```
  // get the specific slide, using the parameter index, from some higher-scoped variable called slides
  var slide = slides[index];
  // if slide isn't falsey, style = slide.style, otherwise style = falsey;
  var style = slide && slide.style;

  // if style is falsey, go away
  if (!style) return;

  // set all these different transition durations, since each browser wants different style settings, all to the same value: speed + 'ms'
  // (reformatted to make the = less confusing)
  style.webkitTransitionDuration = style.MozTransitionDuration = style.msTransitionDuration = style.OTransitionDuration = style.transitionDuration = speed + 'ms';

  style.webkitTransform = 'translate(' + dist + 'px,0)' + 'translateZ(0)';
  // similarly, set all these different transforms to translateX( + dist + px)
  style.msTransform = style.MozTransform = style.OTransform = 'translateX(' + dist + 'px)';
```